# Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code which simply grabs a URL behind HTTP-Basic authentication and re-serves it:

```
<?PHP
    header("Content-Type: text/xml");

    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $url = "http://s6.voscast.com:7158/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml";

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array (
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($username.":".$password)."\r\n".
                        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/14.0.835.202 Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
        )
    ));

    print file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
?>
```

It works without any issues locally on my Linux Mint 11 machine (v. 5.3.5), but fails on another Linux server of a client which is running 5.2.14:

[image]

It seems like it's trying to validate the XML, which is totally unnecessary. Is there a way I can disable this feature or investigate further as to what's going wrong?

When I look at the source of the response, I see the following:

> failed to open stream: Connection refused in **/home/livshin/public_html/wp-content/uploads/_radio/songinfo.php** on line **16**

It's working fine locally, but is failing online? How can I further debug this?

Comment: Have you looked at the source of the page in your browser to see what else is getting appended? Either way, you won't be able to disable the error unless you're actually outputting valid xml.

Comment: Edited my question with an error in the response. It seems that `file_get_contents` is failing online for some reason. What would be the difference between the online server and my local computer?

Comment: If you send a content to the browser and declare it as XML, it will try to process it as XML. You should either make sure you're sending valid XML, have the browser display it as text by using the `text/plain` MIME type, or have the browser download the file using `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: The server might be behind a company firewall and not have outside internet access at all.

Comment: What is that songinfo.php is doing is failing as it can't connect to whatever service it's trying to access. What is that plugin for? a "currently playing" thing that queries spotify or something?

Comment: It's radio station info from a ShoutCast server. The server is public/internet facing, so it shouldn't have any problems making another HTTP request.

Comment: @Inerdia Yeah, just figured that out; it's a browser error trying to process the response as XML, not a problem with my script per se.

Comment: It's perfectly possible (and maybe even common) to configure a network so that web servers only receive and respond to HTTP requests from the internet but are blocked from making outgoing connections to anything but required databases / etc. Make a sanity check like in John Watson's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a simple test case to see if you can access *any* internet website. e.g. `<?php echo file_get_contents('http://google.com'); ?>` Assuming the code and configuration (username/password) is identical on your local machine and the server, then the problem must be that the server itself is different in some way (e.g. doesn't have internet access).

Another thing to check would be the PHP configuration on the server. Opening a URL with `file_get_contents()` can be disabled using the [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) setting.

Comment: I can do that on the server just fine. Is there a way I could get a detailed stacktrace?

Comment: As it turns out (see http://j.mp/tLLeNo), the problem was caused by the server not allowing outbound connections on TCP 7158.

Answer (score 0):

That error is actually coming from the browser that is interpreting the result it got from the php script.

I'm on Safari on Mac, and I'm seeing the same thing when some error message is produced by my php script.

To see the real text (ie the useful error message) returned by the script, I had to show the source code.

In Safari to show source you need to go to Preferences-Advanced, and check "Show Develop menu...". Then when the error is showing, choose "Show Page Source" from the Develop menu.

Then make sure you choose "Source Code" instead of "DOM tree" from the picker just above the box that shows the text.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. The solution was to set the timezone.